# Почему ip адреса в одной сети разные?

Tags: ip

У меня в сети есть несколько компьютеров у них ip адреса 192.168.0.x(192.168.0.5) а у моего телефона 192.168.0.xxx(192.168.0.105) почему так происходит и как "приравнять" все ip? Сделать все адреса одного вида (т.е 192.168.0.xxx)

Comment: Они и так все одного вида, 5 и 005 это одно и то же

Comment: Впрочем, 008 уже быть не может, ибо восьмеричная система счисления на самом деле. Ну а целом непонятно чем такой вид не нравится, IP-адрес это четыре числа от 0 до 255, вместо xxx может стоять любое число от 0 до 255, это всё один и тот же вид

Comment: _Сделать все адреса одного вида (т.е 192.168.0.xxx)_ - тогда уж 192.168.000.ххх!

Answer (score 1):

Если очень нужно, чтобы числа были одинаковой длины, то можено залезть в настройки рутера и сказать ему, чтобы раздавал адреса начиная с 192.168.0.100. Тогда последний октет у всех будет трехзначный. Или даже с 192.168.100.100, тогда все будут трехзначные. Понятно, что 100 можно заменить на любое другое трезначное число, не превышающее 254 (но осторожно, а то может не хватить адресов на все устройства в доме).